# Error when adding assembly to SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, .net-assembly

I'd appreciate if someone can advise on my problem.

I have a class library project with EF version 4.5.

`App.Config` of the project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
    <add name="REPORTSEntities" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
  </entityFramework>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/></startup></configuration>
```

When I try to add the `dll` to SQL Server 2012, I get the error:

> Assembly 'entityframework, version=5.0.0.0, culture=neutral,publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089.' was not found in the SQL catalog. (Error:6503)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try to add required EntityFramework assembly to SQL Server first

Comment: @JesseJames, when i try to add it I get another error: system.data.entity was not found. assebmly entityframework you are registering is not fully tested in SQL server hosted environment and is not supported. In the future,if you upgrade or service this assembly or the .NET framework, your CLR integration routine may stop working.

Comment: Check this thread. Its about your error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304357/how-to-reference-gac-assemblies-when-integrating-a-clr-extension-into-sql-server

Comment: Thanks for the link, so which assembly whould I register? When i try to create EF assembly it requires System.Data.Entity. This in turn requires system.runtime.serialization, and so on..

Comment: Hmm, but why do you want to add assembly to SQL Server? This is called `SQL Server CLR Integration` and used to perform complex operation on SQL Server and data. If you still need it you should extract sqlopeartion into another assembly which won't have references to entity framework

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server's CLR host is fairly restricted / limited by design. Here is a list of the supported .NET Framework libraries (found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279(v=sql.110).aspx)). Notice that it is a fairly short list, and Entity Framework is not in it.

- CustomMarshalers
- Microsoft.VisualBasic
- Microsoft.VisualC
- mscorlib
- System
- System.Configuration
- System.Data
- System.Data.OracleClient
- System.Data.SqlXml
- System.Deployment
- System.Security
- System.Transactions
- System.Web.Services
- System.Xml
- System.Core.dll
- System.Xml.Linq.dll

I can't imagine why there would be a need to load a data access framework when you are running inside of the database itself. To be fair, you *can* do this if you load them all as `UNSAFE`, assuming that they are all pure MSIL and none are mixed. But one of several risks in loading _un_supported .NET Framework libraries is that if they change over time (via Windows Update or manual update) then your code running in SQL Server might stop working. If it is just an updated version then you need to manually update the relevant .NET Framework DLLs that you had to load into SQL Server in order to get this to work in the first place. But, if one of those DLLs changes to mixed in an update, then you won't be able to load the updated version into SQL Server and will have to change your code to not require that DLL anymore.

However, if you do load this, then executing `CREATE ASSEMBLY` while referencing the full path to the EF DLLs, it should automagically pull in all of the dependencies.

That all being said, are you sure you need to load any DLLs into SQL Server? There is no reason to have an `app.config` file for anything running in SQLCLR.

Comment: The thing is that I have a complex logic for building a stored procedure. That's why I decided to code it in C# and use assembly in my sp. Is it a wrong way? any alternative?

Comment: @GyuzalR Complex logic is definitely a good reason to use SQLCLR. But using Entity Framework in SQLCLR? I can't see that as being a benefit. And it might not always work as expected.

Comment: ok..but how can I use database data in my logic without EF then? use SQL connection classes of System.Data.SqlClient?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And use `"Context Connection = true;"` for the connection string. Go to www.sqlservercentral.com , then to Stairways, and find Stairway to SQLCLR.